# Html/Js Input range object dynamically loaded inside a div don't works

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, input

Hi I have an hidden div with a range inside:

```
<div id="hiddencontainer" style="display:none;">
  <input id="range1" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" name="rating"   value="1" onmousemove="showrangevalue()"/>
</div>
```

This range works fine when it is displayed directly but I need to hidde this range and show it when user click on a specific button.

The problem is that after the user click on the "showing range" button, the range is displayed but impossible to read his value.

**The demo and full code on jsbin:**
http://jsbin.com/voyilovuya/3/

**HTML**

```
<div id="hiddencontainer" style="display:none;"><!-- try without display none -->
  <input id="range1" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" name="rating" value="1" onmousemove="showrangevalue()"/>
</div>
<div id="container">

</div>
<div id="value">

</div>

<input type="button" value="Afficher" onClick="showhiddencontainer()"></input>
```

**JS**

```
function showrangevalue(){
  document.getElementById("value").innerHTML=document.getElementById("range1").value;

}
function showhiddencontainer(){
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=document.getElementById("hiddencontainer").innerHTML;
}
```

Have you a solution? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this http://jsfiddle.net/g03srawu/1/,

you are duplicating the `range` element in `container`, so there are two range inputs with same ids,

This will  show the values in the hidden   element inside  `.value` div. replace it with class, and then you can use it.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="hiddencontainer" style="display:none;"><!-- try without display none -->
  <input class="range1" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" name="rating" value="1" onmousemove="showrangevalue()"/>
</div>
<div id="container">

</div>
value:
<div id="value">

</div>

<input type="button" value="Showing range" onClick="showhiddencontainer()"></input>
```

**JS:**

```
function showrangevalue(){
  document.getElementById("value").innerHTML=document.querySelectorAll(".range1")[1].value;

}
function showhiddencontainer(){
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=document.getElementById("hiddencontainer").innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
function showhiddencontainer(){
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=
  document.getElementById("hiddencontainer").innerHTML;
}
```

with

```
function showhiddencontainer(){
    document.getElementById("hiddencontainer").style.display = "block"; 
}
```

unless you have a reason to copy your container over?